# How to make WebView limit screen size

Tags: android, user-interface, android-webview, google-forms

I've noticed that webpages such as this google form are displayed perfectly by any major mobile browser(chrome, stock browser, opera) in that the user cannot side-scroll but can scroll vertically.
[image]

However, in my application's WebView a much larger window is displayed and it becomes possible to side-scroll, which I don't want.
[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

**EDIT:**
After messing around with the form's html I realized that it sets the css style sheet to a mobile version if it detects a screen size less than or equal to 721 px.  So I guess the major browsers I was using somehow "trick" the webpage into thinking a small-screened device is seeing it.  Does anyone know how to do this?

**EDIT2:**
I have found a fairly ugly solution to this by injecting javascript into the webpage once it is done loading.  This is the tag I changed using the injected js:
`<link href='/static/forms/client/css/1446748018-mobile_formview_ltr.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 721px)'>`

And the command I used in the app:      `webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('link')[3].media = 'screen and (max-device-width: 5000px)';");`
In doing this I am setting the maximum screen width at which the mobile css stylesheet will be applied to the webpage to something ridiculously high - 5000px.  This way the mobile css is always applied.

IMO this is a very sloppy solution and if anyone has anything better please share

Comment: what version of Android are you on? Some versions of the WebView report certain sizes in physical pixels, not CSS pixels which could confuse the page.

Comment: The target sdk for the app is 18.  Do you know if this version expresses the properties that you wrote about?

Comment: no, it does not. I'm asking about the version of the Android system (4.4, KitKat, for example) you have on the phone you're testing this on.

Comment: Oh, apologies.  Yeah, I am running 4.4.2, KitKat.

Answer (score 0):

It's because these pages have a mobile viewport but the WebView won't respect that unless you call

```
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried that but it just zooms out.  I'm trying to get the mobile css stylesheet to load instead of the desktop one

Comment: @user3274871 - have you changed the user agent by any chance?

Comment: yes, I also tried that but google forms doesn't seem to care about the user agent.  Like I said it all seems to be dependent on screen size

Comment: see "EDIT" and "EDIT2"

Comment: @user3274871 - is the WebView you're using in wrap_contents mode by any chance? If it is, try setting it to match_parent. wrap_contents messes with the viewport too.